# Are nontrivial solutions for Homogeneous Systems always infinite?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've learned that homogeneous systems can have either: trivial or nontrivial solutions

Trivial which means $x=0$

But I'm unsure with nontrivial. Will it always have a free variable? Example: $x = 2r$, $y = 3r$, $z = r$ where r is a real number

or is it possible to have $x=3$, $y=2$, $z=5$ as nontrivial solution? (I haven't encountered this, just curious) Although I believe this would mean that the system is not homogeneous.

Comment: A homogeneous *linear* system always has the trivial solution.  It may either have no nontrivial solution or many nontrivial solutions.  If you are using real arithmetic then "many" means infinitely many.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a basic technique a system of linear equations can be represented as an [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix).  When the system is *homogeneous*, the right hand side is all zeros and can be omitted for convenience.

When the augmented matrix is put into [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) through a sequence of [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations), the solutions are easily found:  variables corresponding to *leading ones* in the reduced row echelon form are determined by assigning arbitrary values to any variables that *do not correspond* to leading ones.  So if all the variables correspond to leading ones, we get only the trivial solution.  But if at least one variable lacks a leading one, that variable is *free* and can be assigned any value (any real number if that is the field of arithmetic, so an infinite number of solutions are then possible).

Comment: sorry for the late reply. But thank you! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks! I had the feeling you were squared away with the issue of infinitely many solutions, and I mainly posted the Answer to benefit future Readers.